# Thymeleaf + Spring boolean conditions

Tags: html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a template where I want apply some conditions to show 1 icon or another, but no icon is showed, I only see the text (true, false) in the cell

```
<tr th:each="systemAlarm : ${systemAlarms}">

                                        <td class="col_description"  th:text="${systemAlarm.description}" ></td><!-- ID -->
                                        <td class="col_name" th:text="${systemAlarm.enabled}">

                                        <span th:if="${systemAlarm.enabled}"  >
                                            yes<i class="fa fa-bullseye fa-2x" style="color:green; text-align: center;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        <span th:if="${!systemAlarm.enabled}">
                                            no<i class="fa fa-bullseye fa-2x"  style="text-align: center;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        </span>

                                        </td><!-- NAME -->
                                    </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your original html, you have:

```
<td class="col_name" th:text="${systemAlarm.enabled}">
```

the `th:text` attribute overwrites the contents of that `<td>` -- which includes the html for the icons.  You need to remove it.  So, it should look like this:

```
<tr th:each="systemAlarm: ${systemAlarms}">
  <td class="col_description" th:text="${systemAlarm.description}" />
  <td class="col_name">
    <span th:if="${systemAlarm.enabled}">
        yes<i class="fa fa-bullseye fa-2x" style="color:green; text-align: center;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
    <span th:if="${!systemAlarm.enabled}">
        no<i class="fa fa-bullseye fa-2x"  style="text-align: center;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```